# Two Bitwise Criteria in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, enums, bit-manipulation

I have a field in a table representing a business object (HouseType), which represents an enum in .NET or a bitwise flag.

It's used like this:

```
Detached=1
SemiDetached=2
Cottage=4
PrivatelyOwned=8
```

The field can contain any combination of these, so an item could be a Detached, privately owned cottage (=13). I also have a stored procedure (MS SQL 2012) which accepts a parameter and filters out the correct rows like this:

```
    AND (
        U.HouseType IS NULL
         OR (U.HouseType & @HouseType) = 1
         OR (U.HouseType & @HouseType) = 2
         OR (U.HouseType & @HouseType) = 4
         OR (U.HouseType & @HouseType) = 8
    )
```

This works fine if I want to search for one house type, but now I want to search for multiple house types, so if I pass `2` as the @HouseType parameter, I want to show everything which is 2, or some combination of 2 and something else, so pass. Is this possible? The table below shows what I'd like to achieve:

```
HouseType   Query        Returned?
2           2            Yes
4           2            No
6           2            Yes
3           2            Yes
2           3 (2 & 1)    Yes
4           3 (2 & 1)    No
6           4            No
3           5 (4 & 1)    No
```

So if I pass 3 as a parameter for @HouseType, I need to show all rows where HouseType is 1, 2, or 1 & 2

Comment: It would be far better to work with the strengths of the data storage system you've chosen to use - it's designed to *work with* sets. great. But the representation of those sets should be *rows of data*, not primitive bit manipulation. If you can change the representation, I'd encourage you to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to pass three variables to achieve this. I have a property in my business object (.NET) which simplifies the bitwise check..

```
    public HouseTypes HouseType { get; set; }

    public bool HouseTypeDetached
    {
        get { return HouseType.HasFlag(HouseType.Detached); }
        set
        {
            if (value)
            {
                HouseType= HouseType| HouseType.Detached;
            }
            else
            {
                HouseType= HouseType& ~HouseType.Detached;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then pass booleans for each flag value to the stored procedure...

```
AND (
        U.HouseType IS NULL
         OR (@TypeDetached =1 AND (U.HouseType & 1) = 1)
         OR (@TypeCottage = 1 AND (U.HouseType & 2) = 2)
         OR (@TypePrivate = 1 AND (U.HouseType & 4) = 4)
    )
```